# Column width not changing for shared workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this bit of code set to automatically add a new column everyday at a certain time. This macro I set to only apply to one user so there won't be duplicate column created.

```
If Environ("Username") = genericUser Then
    If Range("G11").Value <> Date Then
        Range("G1").EntireColumn.Insert
        Range("G11").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = LDate
        Range("G12").ColumnWidth = 70
        Range("G12").Select
    End If
End If
```

The thing is for any user other than genericUser, the column will show as 14 instead of 70. I fixed this by adding a check (for all users) but I was curious to know if this is an issue with shared workbooks in general or if it's something that can be fixed by altering the macro above.

Note, the fix I mentioned. I included this on workbook open and on auto updates:

```
If Range("G12").ColumnWidth <> 70 Then
    Range("G12").ColumnWidth = 70
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include worksheet for any user other than genericUser?
I think it's needed if you have more than one sheets.

```
If Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet).Range("G12").ColumnWidth <> 70 Then
    Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet).Range("G12").ColumnWidth = 70
End If
```

Hope this help.

Comment: OK, I think it should be updated after the genericUser save the workbook